# Separate docs in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

How can I separate documents which are emailed to me into separate files on Google Drive?

Before I stated using Google Drive I could simply click on a doc and it would highlight blue then I could save it to a file! Google Drive will not allow me to do this.